# Bias of DS literature to polynomial ODEs

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, soft-question, differential-equations

In the literature on continuous time dynamical system, we generally deal with an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector field $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and define a DS by the ODE
$$\mathbf{\dot{x}}=F(\mathbf{x}(t))$$
Most vector fields in the literature are of the form
$$F_j(\mathbf{x})= \sum_{i=1}^m b_i\psi_i(a_i\mathbf{x})$$
where $b_i,a_i$ are real coefficients and $\psi_i: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable functions.

I am mostly interested in multistable DS. Especially in DS with multiple chaotic attractors.

However, when I searched for DS with this property in the literature, I have only found DS using a polynomial VF $F$. By that I mean that $\psi_i$ where multivariate polynomials.  Only in some neuroscience related papers a VF with polynomials and $\psi_i(\mathbf{x})=\tanh(\mathbf{x})$ was used.

---

Can someone point me to literature (maybe some subfield of physics, chemistry, biology, ...) where multistable chaotic DS are discussed which are not polynomial and or $\tanh$ vector fields? (The vector field should still be differentiable)

Comment: I'm no expert--I've looked at simple autonomous ODEs in a single complex variable mainly only for their relation to compositional inversion, formal group laws, and functional iteration a la Schroeder / Abel (e.g., in OEIS A145271), so mainly for my future reference, I have a question for you: Does either "Nonlinear Dynamics: Integrability, Chaos and Patterns" by Lakshmanan and Rajasekar or "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos: With Applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry, and Engineering (Studies in Nonlinearity)" by Strogatz partially address your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book "Elegant Chaos: Algebraically Simple Chaotic Flows" by Julien C. Sprott contains a lot of examples of chaotic systems, including non-polynomial ones. There is also the book "Elegant Circuits: Simple Chaotic Oscillators" by     Julien Clinton Sprott and Wesley Joo-chen Thio, dedicated to chaos in electrical circuits. There, at least one non-polynomial chaotic system with differentiable vector field is described (in the section on tunnel diode circuits). Both books contain an extensive bibliography, from which some additional information can certainly be gleaned.